# How to extract metadata for files on a local server?

Tags: swift, metadata

I am experiencing difficulties getting the metadata from files that are on a local server.

The attached code shows the process I am going through.
The `checkAction` function successfully retrieves the list of files in a selected directory using function `directoryContentsDiskStation`.
For each file in the list I am calling function `getFileMetadata` to extract the required metadata.

When calling this function for files on a local server it does not return any attributes.

On calling this function for files stored on the Mac attributes are returned.

I have tried other solutions namely AVAsset and MDItem but the results are similar.

I have also tried using the server name as part of the URL (`http://DiskStation/`) again to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

```swift
    //directoryArray contains selected Directory
    @objc func checkAction(_ sender: NSButton) {
        //get file list in selected directory
        let fileList = directoryContentsDiskStation(dirName: "/Volumes/Volume/ServerFiles/“+ directoryArray[sender.tag])
        if fileList.count > 0 {
            for j in 0...fileList.count-1 {
                //get metadata for each file in the selected directory
                let fileName = "/Volumes/Volume/ServerFiles/"+ directoryArray[sender.tag]+"/"+fileList[j]
                let codecVals = supportFunctions.getFileMetadata(fileName: fileName)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //returns array containing list of files in selected directory
    func directoryContentsDiskStation(dirName: String) -> [String] {
        var pfadList = [String]()
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let docDir = dirName
        //get list of files in selected directory
        let directoryContents = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docDir)
        if directoryContents != nil {
            if directoryContents!.count > 0 {
                for i in 0...directoryContents!.count-1 {
                    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: docDir+"/"+directoryContents![i]) {
                        //if file exists
                        pfadList.append(directoryContents![i])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return pfadList
    }
    
    //retrieves metadata for selected dataset
    //returns array containing metadata
    class func getFileMetadata(fileName: String) -> [String] {
        let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileName)
        let item = NSMetadataItem(url: path)
        var keyValuePairs = [(key: String, value: Any)]()
        //get the attributes for selected file
        //FILES ON SERVER RETURNS NO ATTRIBUTE VALUES
        //FILES ON LOCAL MAC DO RETURN ATTRIBUTE VALUES
        if let attributes = item!.values(forAttributes: item!.attributes) {
            //loop through file attributes and append to key value array
            for attItem in attributes {
                keyValuePairs.append(attItem)
            }
        }
        //loop through attribute items selecting required metadata values
        var returnVals = ["kMDItemPixelWidth ", "kMDItemPixelHeight ", "kMDItemCodecs ", "kMDItemCodecs " , "kMDItemContentCreationDate ", "kMDItemVideoBitRate "]
        for metaValue in keyValuePairs {
            if metaValue.key == "kMDItemPixelWidth" {
                returnVals[0] = returnVals[0] + String(describing: metaValue.value as! NSNumber)
            }
            if metaValue.key == "kMDItemPixelHeight" {
                returnVals[1] = returnVals[1] + String(describing: metaValue.value as! NSNumber)
            }
            if metaValue.key == "kMDItemCodecs" {
                let codecs = metaValue.value as! NSArray
                for i in 0...codecs.count-1 {
                    if i > 1 {
                        break
                    }
                    returnVals[i+2] = returnVals[i+2] + (codecs[i] as! String)
                }
            }
            if metaValue.key == "kMDItemContentCreationDate" {
                let formatter = DateFormatter()
                formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                returnVals[4] = returnVals[4] + formatter.string(from:((metaValue.value as! NSDate) as Date))
            }
            if metaValue.key == "kMDItemVideoBitRate" {
                returnVals[5] = returnVals[5] + String(describing: metaValue.value as! NSNumber)
            }
        }
        return returnVals
    }
```

Comment: Please learn to format your questions and take the trouble to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your point, however I am getting Metadata values from an external disk but not all elements are available. In particular those related to the Video quality e.g. kMDItemPixelWidth. Do you know how one can change the Spotlight settings so that these values are available?

Comment: I stand by my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The result you're getting is expected. The metadata you are trying to obtain is created locally by the Mac operating system as a convenience for Spotlight indexing. It is not innately present in these files and will not automatically be obtained from files that live elsewhere — e.g. on a volume that isn't maintained by the Mac operating system or isn't indexed by Spotlight, such as a DiskStation volume.